# Show an event with nodejs

Tags: solidity, javascript, events, nodejs, api-design

in my Smart Contract I have a function such that it fires an event at the end of its code.

```
    function sendTran(arguments) public {
    *code*  
    emit Event(argument 1,argument 3,argument 3,argument 4);       
}
```

In nodejs I have an API like this

```
router.post('/send', function (req, res) {
  contractInstance.methods.sendTran(arguments).send({
    *stuff*  
}).on('transactionHash', function(hash){
  console.log(hash);
}).on('error', console.error);
});
```

How can I modify the API so that I can see in res.send the event emitted by the function sendTran?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about `res.send = hash`?

Comment: @goodvibration Your response makes no sense. That would overwrite the `res.send` function, and what does the transaction hash have to do with the event OP is trying to access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logs are included in the [**transaction receipt**](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) but you can retrieve the transaction receipt only once it's mined. Depending on many factors (network congestion, gas price), a transaction can take a few seconds or a few hours to be mined.

That's why I wouldn't recommend to use synchronous HTTP call to do that. A good API is supposed to have a timeout and in your case you can't be absolutely sure that your transaction will be mined on time.

However, if you still want to do this, you can [pull the transaction receipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) every second until you get it:

```
waitForReceipt(hash, 1000).then(function (transactionReceipt) {
    console.log(transactionReceipt)
});


function waitForReceipt(hash, millisecondsInterval) {
    var retryCount = 0;
    var retryCountLimit = 100;

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var timer = setInterval(function () {

            web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash, function(err, rec) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    reject(err)
                }

                if(rec != null) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve(rec);
                    return;
                }

                retryCount++;
                if (retryCount >= retryCountLimit) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    reject("retry count exceeded");
                }
            });

        }, millisecondsInterval);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

I would recommend rather to use WebSocket to handle the asynchronous nature of the blockchain between a client and a server.

Comment: With this method, can I see the arguments of the emitted event? For example, if I have
emit Event (msg.sender, amount, text); in the Smart Contract,
I would like to log, after the use of the API, the three arguments of the event "Event"...

Comment: The transaction receipt includes a field called "logs" [`logs: Array - Array of log objects, which this transaction generated.`] which are the events triggered by this transaction. Each log can be parsed, you will get the event name and each argument.